# android.location.locationlistener is already defined in a single-type import

Tags: android, google-maps

Edit: slightly different as I was getting a request location update error that resulted in the extra import issue.

I am getting a strange error that my locationlistener is already defined in a single type import.[image: is already defined in a single type import]

Not sure what I have done incorrectly?

I was fixing another error where requestLocationUpdates is not recognised.
[image: can not resolve method requestlocationupdates]
Here is my class implement line:

```
public class MapPage extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, android.location.LocationListener {
```

Comment: Issue was related to the requestlocationupdate so other answer did not help in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error happened because in your class your import both

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

Consider to use only one **or** you can use `LocationListenr` without import like

```
private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener googleLocationListener;
private android.location.LocationListener androidLocationListener;
```

Comment: Did not see that.  The requestlocationupdate error was clouding my investigation.  Appreciate the answer.